# NUnitLite get test parameters from file

Tags: c#, nunit-3.0

We have Nunit based test project in VS2015. We have create a NUnitLite project and referenced our test project to this NUnitLite console project. It is running and performing tests correctly.

Problem is that we have some test parameters defined in .runsettings file, which we set from VS 2015 and when running from VS test menu it is running correctly. But when run from NUnitLite console project it is not loading the .runsettings file so all tests fail.

We need a way to input test parameters to NUnitLite or any NUnit console project so that we can give the console running project to client, he can specify test setting in file and can run the test projects.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i got the solution. This problem occured because NUnitLite documentation is not updated. I am using NUnitLite Runner 3.7 and it has --params option available. So in the Console program main method i am passing parameters like this:

```
public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        return new AutoRun(typeof(NunitOrderTest.FirstTest).GetTypeInfo().Assembly).Execute(new string[] { "--params:Web=google" });
    }
```

You can add logic to get parameters from any file like Excel, csv anything and then pass it in above format as arguments.

Comment: I want to add one more command of `--where` in this. Do you know how to do that?